# Finding parameters of a function without external packages in Python

Tags: python

Let's say we've got a function: xa<sup>2</sup> + yb<sup>2</sup> = xc<sup>2</sup> + yd<sup>2</sup>. I know x and y in this equation. What is the best approach here to find number of all possbile solutions to this equation for parameters: a, b, c and d without using any external packages. I'm not looking for super big numbers here as both x, y and a, b, c, d are bounded from 0 to 50. 
I've tried the only thing that came to my mind: four nested loops to find these parameters and it works but it's less than efficient as numbers go up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try asking this in the `mathematics` group.  You do not have a function; you have a quadratic Diophantine equation.  Move the x and y terms to opposite sides, and then apply parametric simplifications.  The math group (or a good browser search) can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what takes so long; even brute force is done in barely a second.

```
import time

x = 2
y = 5
start = time.time()
for a in range(51):
    for c in range(a):
        for d in range(51):
            for b in range(d):
                f = x * (a*a - c*c) - y * (d*d - b*b)
                if f == 0:
                    print(a, b, c, d)

print(time.time() - start)
```

Output:

```
6 1 4 3
7 0 3 4
7 3 3 5
8 1 2 5
8 5 2 7
9 2 1 6
9 7 1 9
10 3 0 7
10 9 0 11
11 1 1 7
11 4 1 8
11 11 1 13
11 0 9 4
11 3 9 5
12 5 2 9
...
50 1 40 19
50 9 40 21
50 13 40 23
50 27 40 33
50 43 40 47
1.0240814685821533
```

Comment: Turns out I had a tiny bug in a function and it caused long computing time.

PS.
There need to be 51 in every range() in for loop :)

Comment: Fine; going to 51 for all four variables creates some degenerate solutions and quadruples the run time ... still not a great problem.  Glad you're un-stuck.